# reading data from response

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id") as HttpWebRequest;  
request .Accept = "application/xrds+xml";  
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request .GetResponse();
```

returns xrds document.
how to read that document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what you're trying to do - if you just need to read what comes back, then you could load the document into an XmlDocument and examine it programmatically e.g.

```
XmlDocument rdsDocument;

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id") as HttpWebRequest;
request.Accept = "application/xrds+xml";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

rdsDocument = new XmlDocument();
rdsDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what what you're after

http://code.google.com/p/myspaceid-csharp-sdk/wiki/OpenStack